# Leverage CreateRecordEvent FeedItem on unrelated Object

Tags: chatter, feeditem

I am trying to determine whether it is possible to display the "compact layout" of a record in the Chatter Feed of another object type. I know that it is possible when the two objects are related via a lookup, as it uses the CreateRecordEvent type of FeedItem when you create the child record via a publisher action. However, I am attempting to create a child object where the relationship is loosely defined (a text field that holds the ID, allowing the object to be used with any other object) via a custom Visualforce publisher action on the Account page.

To illustrate, the FeedItem below is a new contact that I created on the Account page using a publisher action. It shows up on both the Account and the Contact's Feed.

[image]

I can create a different type of FeedItem like a LinkPost to reference the URL of my loosely related record, but would like to maintain the format of a CreateRecordEvent and the compact layout that displays metadata.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to set the LinkPost feed item's attachment to the record summary (i.e. the auxiliary body that is shown in the illustrated example given above). But that is not allowed, at least in the Connect REST API that I've tried. So the scenario what you described above might not be doable.